# loop Ajax Response in select Option tag

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

i have to select multiple tests and date and when clicked on submit based on the test,laboratory names are loaded in select option

**Ajax script**

```
$('[name=submits]').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var array = [];
    $('select :selected').each(function(i,value)
    {
        array[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    var testdate = $("#appointmentdate10").val();
    //here make your ajax call to a php file
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/refer/index.php/details",
        data: { laboratory_tests: array, testdate: testdate },
        success: function(data){
            // alert(data);
            console.log(data);
            var selOpts = "";
            for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                var id = data[i]['laboratory_id'];
                var val = data[i]['laboratory_name'];
                selOpts += "<option value='"+id+"'>"+val+"</option>";
            }
            $('#yourSelect').append(selOpts);
        }
    });
});
```

**Ajax success response is:**

```
[
    {"laboratory_id":"19","laboratory_name":"ghc","laboratory_address":"cgc","laboratory_place":"jhggj","laboratory_tests":"MRI R\/L SHOULDER WITH CONTRAST"},
    {"laboratory_id":"20","laboratory_name":"BBNB","laboratory_address":"sdfds","laboratory_place":"sdfsd","laboratory_tests":"MRI R\/L SHOULDER WITH CONTRAST"},
    {"laboratory_id":"22","laboratory_name":"Anand","laboratory_address":"bsk","laboratory_place":"bengaluru","laboratory_tests":"MRI R\/L SHOULDER WITH CONTRAST"}
]
```

**html**

```
<select class="form-control" id="yourSelect">

</select>
```

but i am not able to display in select tag

Comment: could you check `data[i]['laboratory_id']` in the `console.log(data);`

Comment: The basic $.ajax code works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/kabmqdpt/. Need more details on what is or isn't happening. Please take some time to read [ask]

Comment: yeah but i am getting the value as undefined in my select tag

Answer (score 2):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: config.routes.profitsReport,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i, value) {
                $('#category_profit').append('<option id=' + JSON.stringify(value.id) + '>' + JSON.stringify(value.name) + '</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.statusText + "[" + request.status + "]");
            alert(request.responseText);
            $('button#form_salesReport_button').html(config.messages.searchReport);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. The asker will be happy to understand why your code solves his/her problem.

Comment: A few points that I had to change in my case. First of all using `JSON.stringify` adds quotes `""` to your text in the dropdown. So you can remove it. Then in the error part, the `+ request.status +` causes issues as it won't recognise the variable `request`, so you can also remove this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting json data from ajax request then you need to require to add `dataType` as `json`.

```
$('[name=submits]').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var array = [];
    $('select :selected').each(function(i,value)
    {
        array[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    var testdate = $("#appointmentdate10").val();
    //here make your ajax call to a php file
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost/refer/index.php/details",
        data: { laboratory_tests: array, testdate: testdate },
        success: function(data){
            // alert(data);
            console.log(data);
            var selOpts = "";
            for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                var id = data[i]['laboratory_id'];
                var val = data[i]['laboratory_name'];
                selOpts += "<option value='"+id+"'>"+val+"</option>";
            }
            $('#yourSelect').append(selOpts);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to loop through the result like this:

```
   success: function(data){
            // alert(data);
            console.log(data);
            var selOpts = "";

            $.each(data, function(k, v)
            {
                var id = data[k].laboratory_id;
                var val = data[k].laboratory_name;
                selOpts += "<option value='"+id+"'>"+val+"</option>";
            });
            $('#yourSelect').append(selOpts);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop

```
[
    {"laboratory_id":"19","laboratory_name":"ghc","laboratory_address":"cgc","laboratory_place":"jhggj","laboratory_tests":"MRI R\/L SHOULDER WITH CONTRAST"},
    {"laboratory_id":"20","laboratory_name":"BBNB","laboratory_address":"sdfds","laboratory_place":"sdfsd","laboratory_tests":"MRI R\/L SHOULDER WITH CONTRAST"},
    {"laboratory_id":"22","laboratory_name":"Anand","laboratory_address":"bsk","laboratory_place":"bengaluru","laboratory_tests":"MRI R\/L SHOULDER WITH CONTRAST"}
]
```

via

```
var options = "";
for (let item in array) {
    options += `<option value=${item.id}>${item.laboratory_name}</option>`;
}
document.getElementById("yourSelect").innerHTML = options;
```

If it's a String, you can convert it to an array via `JSON.parse`.