# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Ajax GET

Tags: json, ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

I need your help...

Primary controller :

@Controller
public class WaitingListController {

```
@Autowired
private WaitingListRepository waitingListRepo;
@Autowired
private DepartmentRepository depRepo;

@Autowired
private PatientRepository paitentRepo;

@Autowired
private SurgeonRepository surgeonRepo;

@GetMapping("/surgerywaitinglist")
public ModelAndView getAll() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("list");
    mav.addObject("waitinglist", waitingListRepo.findAll());
    return mav;
}

@GetMapping(value="/surgerywaitinglist/patientSearch")
public ModelAndView patientSearch() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("patientSearch");
    Patient patient =new Patient();
    mav.addObject("patient", patient);
    return mav;
}

@GetMapping(value="/surgerywaitinglist/addProcedure")
public ModelAndView addProcedure( Long patientId) {
//public ModelAndView addProcedure() {
    
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("addProcedure");
    Patient patient = paitentRepo.findById(patientId).get();
    List<Surgeon> surgeons = surgeonRepo.findAll();
    List<Department> departments = depRepo.findAll();
    WaitingList waitinglist = new WaitingList();
    mav.addObject("patient", patient);
    mav.addObject("surgeons", surgeons);
    mav.addObject("departments", departments);
    mav.addObject("waitinglist", waitinglist);
    
    return mav;
}

@PostMapping(value="/surgerywaitinglist/saveToWaitinList")
public String saveToWaitinList(@ModelAttribute WaitingList waitinglist, Long patientId) {
    if(waitinglist.getWaitingListId()==null) {
        waitinglist.setWaitingListPatientId(patientId);
        waitingListRepo.save(waitinglist);
    }
    
    else {
        
        waitinglist.setWaitingListActualBookingDate(waitinglist.getWaitingListActualBookingDate());
        waitinglist.setWaitingListAdditionDate(waitinglist.getWaitingListAdditionDate());
        waitinglist.setWaitingListProcedure(waitinglist.getWaitingListProcedure());
        waitinglist.setWaitingListDiagnosis(waitinglist.getWaitingListDiagnosis());
        waitinglist.setWaitingListSurgeonId(waitinglist.getWaitingListSurgeonId());
        waitinglist.setWaitingListDepartmentId(waitinglist.getWaitingListDepartmentId());
        waitingListRepo.save(waitinglist);
    }
    return "redirect:/surgerywaitinglist";
    
}
```

}

Secondary Controller:

```
package com.WaitingListThymeleaf.controller;
```

@RestController
public class SurgeonController {

```
@Autowired
private SurgeonRepository surgeonRepo;

@GetMapping("surgeons")
public List<Surgeon> getAll(){
    return surgeonRepo.findAll();
}
@GetMapping("surgeon/{surgeonSpeciality}")
public List<Surgeon> findBySurgeonSpeciality(@PathVariable Long surgeonSpeciality) {
    
    List<Surgeon> surgeons = surgeonRepo.findBySurgeonspeciality(surgeonSpeciality);
    
    return surgeons;
    
}
```

}

HTML page (body only):

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <h3>Add New Procedure</h3>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />
    <form th:action="@{saveToWaitinList}" th:object="${waitinglist}"
        method="POST">

        <table class="table table-primary table-bordered table-striped"
            id="employeeTable" style="width: 50%" align="center">
            <thead>

            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>MRN</td>
                    <td th:text="${patient.patientId}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td
                        th:text="${patient.patientFirstName} +' '+ ${patient.patientLastName}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                    <td th:text="${patient.patientGender}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact</td>
                    <td th:text="${patient.patientConact}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Procedure</td>
                    <td><input type="text"
                        th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListProcedure}"
                        class="form-control col-4 mb-4" placeholder="Enter Procedure" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Diagnosis</td>
                    <td><input type="text"
                        th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListDiagnosis}"
                        class="form-control col-4 mb-4" placeholder="Enter Diagnosis" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Choose Department</td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="department">

                            <select th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListDepartmentId}"
                                onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">

                                <option th:each="department: ${departments}"
                                    th:value="${department.departmentId}"
                                    th:text="${department.departmentName}"></option>

                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <!-- <input type="text"
                        th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListDepartmentId}"
                        class="form-control col-4 mb-4" placeholder="Enter Department" /> -->

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Surgeon</td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <div id="SurgeonId">
                            <select>
                                <option value="" disabled>Select Department First</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    <!--  Before AJAX Implementation
                    <td><input type="text"
                        th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListSurgeonId}"
                        class="form-control col-4 mb-4" placeholder="Enter MRP" /></td>
                        
                         -->
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Addition Date</td>
                    <td><input type="date"
                        th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListAdditionDate}"
                        class="form-control col-4 mb-4" placeholder="Pick Date" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Acttual Booking Date</td>
                    <td><input type="date"
                        th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListActualBookingDate}"
                        class="form-control col-4 mb-4" placeholder="Pick Date" /></td>
                </tr>



            </tbody>


        </table>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <br /> <input type="hidden" th:field="${patient.patientId}" />

        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>

    </form>
    <br /> <br />
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <a th:href="@{/surgerywaitinglist}">Back To List</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript AJAX Code:

```
<script>
function showCustomer(str) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("SurgeonId").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/surgeon/" + str, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

On the client side I get the pulled data as JSON as you can see:

[image]

How can I manipulate the pulled data into select/option tag in the HTML page?

.... Update....

I edited the AJAX script as follows:

```
   <script>
    function showSurgeons(str) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                //var log = xmlhttp.responseText;
                //console.log(log);
                //const res = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                //Object.entries(res).forEach((entry) => {
                //  const [key, value] = entry;
                //  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
                //});
                
                /* xmlhttp.onload = function(){
                    var ourData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    console.log(ourData);
                } */
                        
                
                //document.getElementById("SurgeonId").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var ourData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                var innerHTMLTest = '<select th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListSurgeonId}"> ';
                for(i=0; i<ourData.length; i++){
                    innerHTMLTest +=' <option th:value="'+ ourData[i].surgeonId + '" th:text="' + ourData[i].surgeonLastName + '"></option>';
                }
                
                innerHTMLTest += ' </select>';
                console.log(innerHTMLTest);
                //document.getElementById("SurgeonId").innerHTML = ourData.surgeonId;
                document.getElementById("SurgeonId").innerHTML = innerHTMLTest;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/surgeon/" + str, false);
        
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

It seems it is working-is... In the console I get the following:

```
<select th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListSurgeonId}">  <option th:value="13505" th:text="Zah"></option> <option th:value="13000" th:text="Abdulkareem"></option> </select>
```

which is exactly what I needed... However, nothin shows on the template as you can see :
[image]

Today's update :)

Apparently, the code works even though it not showing in the select/option as you can see in the attached image below !
When I inspect the document.body (DOM) in the background... It is there! but not visible... I checked the database... the mySQL INSERTed successfully !

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the MySQL Workbench:

[image]

Successfully added !

Comment: You will have to form dynamic elements by using the response and render it to html using jQuery/js

Comment: thank you.. I will try it out and update you with the feedback :)

Comment: I have been trying to work it out with no luck... I've been searching the web no luck either.... Could somebody help me out or guide me to webpage....

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/q/43868298/6572971

Comment: I had a look on the link above.... It was too advanced... I just started using Thymeleaf with less than average of JS :(

Comment: I think I am on the right track.... on step to go guys...

Comment: Note to admins: my question got diverged into branches !!
Should I created another thread?
Thanx for sharing knowledge